# Jquery ->Timepicker : How do i add zero value in every single digit hour in timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

i have a timepicker like this :

```
$('#datepickerTime').timepicker({
    timeFormat : "hh:mm:ss"
});
```

but when time is 1 to 9 it will not add zero to the front(eg. 01:30), How do i add zero in from of every single digit hours? thanks

Comment: Your syntax is right please go through this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/74/).

Comment: im not getting a dropdown list instead im getting an arrow up and arrow down separated hours mins and seconds

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your code?

Comment: Is this http://timepicker.co/ the time picker you are using? If not, which one are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shlould initialize timepicker with this ::

```
$('#datepickerTime').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i:s' });
```

this will generate the output showing in image::

[image]

**UPDATED As per comment**::

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="datepickerTime" id="datepickerTime" />
```

Comment: @microprogramming is there showing any error message in console?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the timeFormat.

```
$('#datepickerTime').timepicker({
    timeFormat : "HH:mm:ss"
});
```

Comment: What kind of plug is timepicker?